# Insert 2 values into MySQL, and then stop said values appearing again

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a script, its supposed to insert a vote (either -1 or +1) to a MySQL value, it does this fine, but it's also supposed to insert the ID of the item they have just voted on, into another table, in array format, to the user who has just voted, so that it doesn't appear again for that user.

1) I don't know how to stop the values appearing again
2) It's not sending the id of the website

The code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM webmash ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entry from table webmash.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
    $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
    $link =($row['link']);
    $votes = ($row['votes']);
    $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM webmashusers";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entry from table webmashusers.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $username = stripslashes($row['username']);
    $likes = ($row['likes']);
    $dislikes = ($row['dislikes']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
    $votes += 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE webmash SET votes = $votes WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
    mysql_query($sql);

    $sqllikes = array (serialize($id));
    $sql2 = "INSERT '$sqllikes' INTO webmashusers (likes) WHERE 'username' = '$376770'";
    mysql_query($sql2);
    }


    if(isset($_POST['dislike'])) {
    $votes -= 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE webmash SET votes = $votes WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
    mysql_query($sql);

    $sqldislikes = array (serialize($id));
    $sql2 = "INSERT '$sqldislikes' INTO webmashusers (dislikes) WHERE 'username' = '$376770'";
    mysql_query($sql2);

    }
```

EDIT: $376770 is my username cookie.

Comment: -1 because of SQL-injection hole.

Comment: May I suggest you look into PDO for prepared statements. Alternatively mysqli or just `mysql_real_escape_string` would be better than nothing! At the moment your code has a gaping hole for SQL-injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Saving serialized arrays in mysql isn't a good way.

Anyway I think you have a couple of errors starting with:

```
 $sqllikes = array (serialize($id));
```

basically you are serializing a simple `int` ?

`$id` is previsouly setted to = `$row['id'];`

That makes 0 sense.

You should store just the int of the ID in a single column and maybe to avoid duplicate insert you can make it `UNIQUE` with the other key.

Comment: It has to be set to that because that's where its getting the ID of the item from.

Comment: How would you recommend storing the array then?

Comment: I would not store the array at all. I'd just store the ID in a column, maybe with a UNIQUE constraint with the other foreign key so it can't get duplicated value

Answer (score 0):

Side note, you use $_POST['id'] in raw query.. way vulnerable for sql injections.

```
$sql = "UPDATE webmash SET votes = $votes WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
```

As for your question, you use INSERT, even if there is already such user in the second table. UPDATE should be useful in the case. Overall, you could google for "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE" Mysql syntax for $sql2 queries and use it (together with making user name unique index in second table).